# Как узнать текущее время и текущую дату системы - C++

Tags: c++

Как узнать время и дату системы в C++ не прибегая к WINAPI?
P. S. Пожалуйста извините, что нету кода)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
time_t seconds = time(NULL);
tm* timeinfo = localtime(&seconds);
cout<<"Текущее время и дата:"<<asctime(timeinfo)<<endl;
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

См. `time()`

Если перевести в нормальные показания :) - применить к полученному от `time()` времени `localtime()`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time( &rawtime );                         // текущая дата, выраженная в секундах
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );        // текущая дата, представленная в нормальной форме
  std::cout << "Текущая дата/время : "
            << asctime (timeinfo);

  return 0;
```