# Как отобразить данные по условию текущей дате?

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть структура `concert`, которая хранит дату выступления артистов.

```
struct concert{
     string name;
     string groupname;
     int day;
     int month;
     int year;
};
```

Как мне вывести данные о концертах, которые будут в ближайшие 17 дней?

Comment: [Получение текущей даты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690309/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-c)

Comment: Ето не то ,мне нунжо сделать операции с датой.

Comment: Чтобы получить данные о концертах в ближайшие 17 дней, Вам необходимо знать текущую дату, нет?

Comment: Да нужно но как потом манипулировать не знаю

Comment: Я разделил с помощю chrono но как теперь мне разделить ету дату ? Ето уже другой вопрос.